# How remove "open app tumblr" message?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

I'm interested in use tumblr for blogging, and I found an amazing responsive theme but I want to know if it's possible remove "Open in the Tumblr app" message, and how can I do it.

[openapptumblr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1K4i.png)

*I'm new in stackoverflow, excuse me if I'm wrong opening this thread and sorry for my english.*

Comment: No, it is not possible to remove the message. This is added by Tumblr when you tumblr blog is requested.

Comment: I guess it's possible and I overcame this issue, but I only tested it on [my site](https://jorgeamvf.com) and on an Android and a PC. Please, try the couple of codes I provided on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49656888/6398434) and see if it works in your case.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this solution suggested by u/felix4343](https://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/3vtb1z/removing_openinstall_the_app_header_toolbar_from/cy912bj) and it solved my issue at least on Android:

```
tumblr_controls, .tmblr-iframe{display:none!important;}
```

Also, I was using [this piece of code](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/116025/183743) before stumbling upon the mobile issue and it was working for PC:

```
.tmblr-iframe-compact .tmblr-iframe--unified-controls {display: none!important;}
```

In doubt, like me, test both:

```
.tmblr-iframe-compact .tmblr-iframe--unified-controls {display: none!important;}

tumblr_controls, .tmblr-iframe{display:none!important;}
```

Pay attention because you might not find an easy way to edit your theme anymore, but you can still find the panel by just clikcing on your blog from the dashboard or directly at www.tumblr.com/customize/[yourblog].

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

- profile pic >>
- edit appearance >>
- edit theme >>
- advanced options >>
- uncheck 'use default mobile theme' !

worked for me, probably theme dependent.. good luck!
:D yeew