# Hide Tumblr Floating Banner

Tags: tumblr

I would like to hide the banner that appears on Tumblr, both in the web version and in the mobile version. Maybe with CSS or html.

[image]

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49656888/1238244 You need to add some css to your theme. I actually think there is a better way to do this in 2022. But it would involve hiding all of the tumblr iframes (some of these you might actually need to be able to process certain actions on your account).

Answer (score 1):

The banner uses the class name .follow-teaser. Just add the following to your css

`.follow-teaser {display: none}`

Answer (score 0):

Insert this into your CSS:

```
.tmblr-iframe--follow-teaser {
    display:none!important;
}
```

.follow-teaser does not work anymore.